# Object conversion in .NET framework

Tags: c#, type-conversion, .net-4.8

I'm new to .NET framework. I'm struggling in object type conversion where I need to convert another class object from one.

Let's say I have two classes and both are inheriting or implementing the same class. I want to convert to one object to another class object.
Is that possible?

If yes please provide your solution code.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Child1 child1 = new Child1();
        child1.print_me();
        Child2 child2 = (Child2)((Base)child1); // Facing this line conversion error in runtime and not in compile time.
        child2.print_me();
    }

    private class Base
    {
        public void print_me()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am Base");
        }
    };

    private class Child1 : Base
    {
        public new void print_me()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am Child1");
        }
    };

    private class Child2 : Base
    {
        public new void print_me()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am Child2");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That's not possible. A `Child1` is not a `Child2` therefore you cannot convert from one to the other.

Comment: Why do you think you *can* do this?  Why do you think you *need* to?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't work. I'm changing your class names a bit to make your conceptual mistake more obvious:

```cs
class Animal
{
    public virtual void print_me()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am an Animal"); 
    }
};

class Lion: Animal
{
    public override void print_me()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Lion!"); 
    }
};
class Giraffe: Animal 
{
    public override void print_me()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("I am a Giraffe"); 
    }
};
```

Now if you have `Animal a = new Lion()` how could this possibly become a Giraffe? It is a Lion disguised as an Animal, but if you remove that disguise, it's still a lion and will never become a giraffe.

Additionally, to get your intended behavior, the `print_me` method needs to be virtual so that `a.print_me()` outputs "I am a Lion" and not "I am an Animal". In this case, that's a bit of an advanced topic, but you want to read up about static and dynamic type inference for method calls.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination with example code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing custom classes you need to specify how the conversion should be done. There is nothing that can automagicaly figure out how to convert an apple to an orange. There are multiple ways to specify such conversions:

1. [Create an explicit or implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)
2. Add a method to your class to convert it to some other class.
3. Create a constructor that with the type to convert as a constructor argument.

In each case you need to copy any relevant properties over to the new object, and this is generally the difficult part. If the classes has the same properties, should they really be different classes? If they have different properties, how will you resolve the difference?

In your specific example your classes have *no* properties at all. So a conversion operator would just look like:

```
public static explicit operator Child2(Base b) => new Child2();
```

And this would in practice just be the same as `new Child2()`, so it is arguable if there is any real "conversion" going on at all.